# Spring Maven AWS S3 Bucket -> Unable to retrieve the requested metadata (/latest/user-data/). Failed to connect to service endpoint:

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, amazon-s3

I am setting up this project with Spring, Maven, and MongoDB. I am encountering an issue when running the application because it seems that I have an error in the AWS configuration.

application.properties

```
spring.data.mongodb = localhost
spring.data.mongodb.port = 27017
spring.data.mongodb.database=youtube
#####Amazon WebService
cloud.aws.region.static=us-east-1
cloud.aws.stack.auto=false

cloud.aws.credentials.access-key=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
cloud.aws.credentials.secret-key=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
aws.region=us-east-1
cloud.aws.region.use-default-aws-region-chain=true
cloud.aws.ec2.metadata.enabled=false
```

VideostreamingApplication.java

```
package com.fitomx19.videostreaming;
import io.awspring.cloud.context.config.annotation.EnableContextInstanceData;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableContextInstanceData
public class VideostreamingApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(VideostreamingApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

S3Service.java

```
package com.fitomx19.videostreaming.service;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.CannedAccessControlList;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.ObjectMetadata;

import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.util.StringUtils;
import org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile;
import org.springframework.web.server.ResponseStatusException;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.UUID;

@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class S3Service implements FileService {

    public static final String BUCKET_NAME = "bucketvideosfito";
    private final AmazonS3Client awsS3Client;

    @Override
    public String uploadFile(MultipartFile file) {
        var filenameExtension = StringUtils.getFilenameExtension(file.getOriginalFilename());

        var key = UUID.randomUUID().toString() + filenameExtension;

        var metadata = new ObjectMetadata();
        metadata.setContentLength(file.getSize());
        metadata.setContentType(file.getContentType());

        try {
            awsS3Client.putObject(BUCKET_NAME, key, file.getInputStream(), metadata);
        } catch (IOException ioException) {
            throw new ResponseStatusException(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR,
                    "An Exception occured while uploading the file");
        }

        awsS3Client.setObjectAcl(BUCKET_NAME, key, CannedAccessControlList.PublicRead);

        return awsS3Client.getResourceUrl(BUCKET_NAME, key);
    }
}
```

pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>com.fitomx19.videostreaming</groupId>
        <artifactId>videostreaming</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <artifactId>backend</artifactId>
    <name>Archetype - backend</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.awspring.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-aws-context</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.awspring.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-aws-autoconfigure</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-s3</artifactId>
            <version>1.12.395</version>
        </dependency>



    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>17</source>
                    <target>17</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

VideoController.java

```
package com.fitomx19.videostreaming.controller;

import com.fitomx19.videostreaming.service.VideoService;
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;
import org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/videos")
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class VideoController {

    private final VideoService videoService;

    @PostMapping
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
    public void uploadVideo(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file) {
        videoService.uploadVideo(file);
    }
}
```

My structure is this ->

```
backend
--src
  --main
    --java
       --com.fitomx19.videostreaming
           --controller
             videoController
           --model
             Comment
             User
             Video
             VideoStatus
           --repository
             VideoRepository
           --service
             FileService
             S3Service
             VideoService
           VideostreamingApplication.java
```

I am setting up this project with Spring, Maven, and MongoDB. I am encountering an issue when running the application because it seems that I have an error in the AWS configuration.

application.properties

```
spring.data.mongodb = localhost
spring.data.mongodb.port = 27017
spring.data.mongodb.database=youtube
#####Amazon WebService
cloud.aws.region.static=us-east-1
cloud.aws.stack.auto=false

cloud.aws.credentials.access-key=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
cloud.aws.credentials.secret-key=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
aws.region=us-east-1
cloud.aws.region.use-default-aws-region-chain=true
cloud.aws.ec2.metadata.enabled=false
```

VideostreamingApplication.java

```
package com.fitomx19.videostreaming;
import io.awspring.cloud.context.config.annotation.EnableContextInstanceData;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableContextInstanceData
public class VideostreamingApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(VideostreamingApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

S3Service.java

```
package com.fitomx19.videostreaming.service;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.CannedAccessControlList;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.ObjectMetadata;

import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.util.StringUtils;
import org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile;
import org.springframework.web.server.ResponseStatusException;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.UUID;

@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class S3Service implements FileService {

    public static final String BUCKET_NAME = "bucketvideosfito";
    private final AmazonS3Client awsS3Client;

    @Override
    public String uploadFile(MultipartFile file) {
        var filenameExtension = StringUtils.getFilenameExtension(file.getOriginalFilename());

        var key = UUID.randomUUID().toString() + filenameExtension;

        var metadata = new ObjectMetadata();
        metadata.setContentLength(file.getSize());
        metadata.setContentType(file.getContentType());

        try {
            awsS3Client.putObject(BUCKET_NAME, key, file.getInputStream(), metadata);
        } catch (IOException ioException) {
            throw new ResponseStatusException(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR,
                    "An Exception occured while uploading the file");
        }

        awsS3Client.setObjectAcl(BUCKET_NAME, key, CannedAccessControlList.PublicRead);

        return awsS3Client.getResourceUrl(BUCKET_NAME, key);
    }
}
```

pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>com.fitomx19.videostreaming</groupId>
        <artifactId>videostreaming</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <artifactId>backend</artifactId>
    <name>Archetype - backend</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.awspring.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-aws-context</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.awspring.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-aws-autoconfigure</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-s3</artifactId>
            <version>1.12.395</version>
        </dependency>



    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>17</source>
                    <target>17</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

VideoController.java

```
package com.fitomx19.videostreaming.controller;

import com.fitomx19.videostreaming.service.VideoService;
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;
import org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/videos")
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class VideoController {

    private final VideoService videoService;

    @PostMapping
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
    public void uploadVideo(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file) {
        videoService.uploadVideo(file);
    }
}
```

My structure is this ->

```
backend
--src
  --main
    --java
       --com.fitomx19.videostreaming
           --controller
             videoController
           --model
             Comment
             User
             Video
             VideoStatus
           --repository
             VideoRepository
           --service
             FileService
             S3Service
             VideoService
           VideostreamingApplication.java
```